# Unsync Hotmail contacts

Tags: contacts, windows-live, outlook

I added my Windows Live account to my phone recently and my contacts (people tab) got populated with the hotmail email addresses of all my contacts. This is cluttering up my contacts with redundant names (they already exist with gmail and Facebook syncs), so I want to unsync all my hotmail contacts from my contact list.

I've tried going to Settings > Windows Live account and unchecking the 'Sync email' option but this doesn't seem to remove any of them from my existing contact list. Is there a way to at least merge the hotmail email addresses of my contacts with my existing contacts' gmail addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [manually merge contacts](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/people/link-two-or-more-contacts.aspx) by going individually to each contact, clicking the "link" icon, and selecting the contact to merge with.

Comment: +1 This really pays off to do, which enables the pure power of the People Hub: Choosing in which you will contact the user, is the user at home? Simply switch from SMS to a less costly service... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't unsync them, but you can filter them. Go to Settings > Applications > People and click "filter my contact list". There you can select the sources from where your contact list will be populated.

The other option is to merge contact data from different sources, but it can be a bit tedious if you have lots of them.

Answer (score 0):

On the Samsung ATIV Odyssey:

1. Go to People
2. Settings
3. filter my contact list
4. Uncheck Hotmail